# Top N most popular web sites

Tags: hadoop

am trying to learn Hadoop and i have server farm that has millions of web pages. I need t figure out which are the top ten most popular web pages. how to do this in Hadoop ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the basic Wordcount example. 
You simply replace the idea of 'word in text' with 'url'.

I just realized I have something like this already on github available as an example of a library I wrote a while ago: https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser/blob/master/examples/apache-hadoop-mapreduce/src/main/java/nl/basjes/hadoop/io/input/Wordcount.java

Comment: Well, this kinda skips over the ingestion part of the web logs into HDFS

Comment: I only answered the question. And given the current clarity of this question I chose to limit myself to what was actually asked. (Instead of doing his homework for him)

Comment: Sure, but you're just feeding the help vampire by vaguely answering